# Which hand does Link have the triforce on?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

I was wondering which hand Link is supposed to have the triforce glow from. I can't find any standard, and the image I have found have it on both hands, which I expect is a product of the people posting the images flipping the image.

Any insights?

Comment: Depends on whether or not you're playing on the Nintendo Wii. :P

Comment: @GnomeSlice - I call shenannigans! I can think of at least four ways to play Zelda on the Wii that don't agree with you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Link carries the Triforce on his left hand, while Zelda and Gannondorf carry it on their right.

Link also carries his sword in his left hand, so we know he's left handed. Zelda and Gannondorf both appear to be right-handed.

Comment: That matches the imagery from the Super Smash Bros Melee intro (where Link, Gannondorf, and Zelda cross hands in the shape of a triangle). Link's is on his left hand, and the others have it on their right.

Comment: Although he was flipped in the Wii version to match with the motion controls and in the sprite games he always held it in his closest hand to save on sprites and so was right handed when facing right

Comment: @Ronan - The Official Link to the Past Strategy Guide handwaves this by claiming that Link switched hands so that his shield was always pointing towards Death Mountain (North in the game) on account of Hylian superstitions.